# Get value from promise react native and cominbing to Axios header

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, axios, react-native

I'm new on react native, so i want to get value from a function and combining it to axios header.

```js
const getSecurityKey = async () => {
    try {
        const securityKey = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@securityKey')
        return securityKey != null ? JSON.parse(securityKey) : null
    } catch (e) {
        return false
    }
}

instance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {

    config.headers['X-Security-Key'] = getSecurityKey()

    return config
}, function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error)
})
```

how is this possible to get the value

Comment: Is your `securityKey` already returning a resolved promise? If so, try the following (you will need to make your interceptor async): `instance.interceptors.request.use(async function (config) {
    config.headers['X-Security-Key'] = await getSecurityKey()
    return config;
}...`

Comment: Just posted the answer, for future coders!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make your `interceptors` async, like:

```
instance.interceptors.request.use(async function(config) {
  config.headers['X-Security-Key'] = await getSecurityKey();
  return config;
}, function (error) {
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```